# What is the snake like long thing on the ears?

Tags: web

I found this in a webpage. What is the long thing that is growing from these ears? It is found even in the source code. How is this coded?

ด้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็็็้้( ͡° ͜ʖ͡°)ด้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้้้้็็็็็้้้้

The screenshot shown below is taken from [here.](https://twitter.com/Android/status/552950360562618368?utm_source=fb&utm_medium=fb&utm_campaign=danieljeevan&utm_content=553579432145739776)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to wonderful world of Unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to [Unicode Escaping Tools](http://unicode.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php) this ด้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็็็้้( ͡° ͜ʖ͡°)ด้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้้้้็็็็็้้้้

is

```
%u0E14%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E49%u0E49%28%20%u0361%B0%20%u035C%u0296%u0361%B0%29%u0E14%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E47%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49%u0E49
```

Comment: But why are they not shown in this form in the source code? I guess they should be shown as `%u0E14%u0E49%u0E49%u.....` in the source code.

Comment: the escaped form is what you can use in a safe manner in source code, but if your programming language supports unicode you can use those chars directly.

Comment: more precisely those chars where entered by a user and stored as unicode characters. the server delivered them to you coded in utf-8.